# Why is this code in nginx not causing buffer overflow?

Tags: c, nginx

Quoted from [ngx_hash.c](http://ngx_strlow%28elt-%3Ename,%20names%5Bn%5D.key.data,%20names%5Bn%5D.key.len%29;):

```
ngx_strlow(elt->name, names[n].key.data, names[n].key.len);
```

Which copies the lower case string to `elt->name`.

Here `elt` is of type `ngx_hash_elt_t *`:

```
typedef struct {
    void             *value;
    u_short           len;
    u_char            name[1];
} ngx_hash_elt_t;
```

As you see `name` is only `1` char wide,IMO the `ngx_strlow` will cause buffer overflow,but it actually works with no problem,anyone can explain it?

Comment: I would have written u_char name[0]; so that empty string doesn't take room (and made obvious that memory is going to be allocated after the struct)

Comment: @yfroneaud: Arrays of zero size are prohibited by the language (but supported by some compilers as an extension).

Comment: The name of this trick is "the struct hack". C99 standardized (kinda) it with the "flexible array member": see 6.7.2.1 in [the standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually structure of this sort are defined so that the programmer (if she wanted len=100) can go:

```
ngx_hash_elt_t *X;
X = malloc(sizeof(ng_has_elt_t)+99);
```

In this case it is still valid and meaningful for the user and library to reference X.name because it is a pointer to the start of a string.

Comment: Really?  I'd love to hear about them, because I find myself doing this from time to time.

Comment: this kind of pattern is not found there:( http://lxr.evanmiller.org/http/source/core/ngx_hash.c

Comment: @Clark Kant - thought this was c++ question - in straight C there are few alternatives you are correct, have remove the facile ending

Comment: @Je Rog have looked, believe the line  elt = (ngx_hash_elt_t *) ngx_align_ptr(&elt->name[0] + elt->len,sizeof(void *)); in your linked source is extracting a data from beyond the end of the struct using exactly this logic.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the structure is allocated on the heap with malloc().

It could work something like this:

```
size_t decent_length = <something big enough to hold a string>;

ngx_hash_elt_t *elt = malloc (sizeof (*p) + decent_length);
```

Comment: @Je Rog, true. This can sometimes be solved by realloc, but depends on the structure, if it contains pointers to within itself for instance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a trick to create variable length buffers with C. Make the last element 1 byte long, and allocate more. For this structure, allocating an `ngx_hash_elt_t` could be done like the following, for example:

```
ngx_hash_elt_t* alloc_hash_elt(int name_len)
{
    return malloc(sizeof(ngx_hash_elt_t) - 1 + name_len);
}
```

The extra space you allocate can now be safely used by the `name` element.

Answer (score 0):

If elt was allocated as

```
elt = (ngx_hash_elt_t*)malloc(sizeof(ngx_hash_elt_t));
```

, then it will cause an overflow with strings longer than 1. However, most probably, it was allocated as:

```
elt = (ngx_hash_elt_t*)malloc(sizeof(ngx_hash_elt_t) + maximum_possible_length);
```

, so there isn't an overflow.